# Is there any way to use OData $orderby on complex type?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, odata, edmx

Example:

```
public class Address 
{
   public string Address1 {get; set;}
   public string Address2 {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
   public int Id{get; set;}
   //Complex type
   public Address Address{get; set;}
}
```

I have a grid that is fill with data of User. I want to make $orderby by Address, is this posible?

Comment: yep, its possible :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the List object:

```
public class AddressObject
{
   public string Address {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public List<AddressObject> adressList = new List<AddressObject>();
}
```

Than you can order with LINQ:

```
var orderedAdressList = adressList.OrderBy(z => z.Address)
```